# Setting background image of submit button in Symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

Instead of having a basic submit button that reads 'Search', I would like to set a background image of the button to an image of a search icon. I am not sure how to go about it because the entire form is set up in the controller as follows:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('', 'form', $search, array('csrf_protection' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'searchForm')))
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('_search'))
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->add('q', 'text', array('label'=>false, 'required' =>false))
            ->add('search', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
```

And I am currently rendering my Symfony form with Twig:

```
<div class="searchFormWrapper">
    {{ form(form) }}
</div>
```

I also tried this, however it renders the entire button search button and doesn't allow me to set the background image:

```
{{ form_widget(form.q) }}
{{ form_widget(form.search) }}
```

I appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a CSS class to that button by:

```
->add('search', 'submit', array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'my-custom-button-class'))
)
```

and style it in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the button value is automatically set to the word 'Search'. I would like the ID / Name to be 'search' but the value to be empty, so I can set a background image.

Comment: Just skip `search` label like this `->add('', 'submit', arr(...)`

Comment: You really don't want to set the value as empty as screen readers will not be able to know what the button is for.

Comment: So maybe `text-indent:-9000px;` should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This ended up working well. Just feels a bit hacky, thats all ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to style it using CSS. E.g:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .searchFormWrapper button {
        display: inline-block;
        width:100px;
        height:40px;
        background:url('PATH TO YOUR IMAGE') top left no-repeat;
        text-indent:-9000px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        line-height: -9999px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however button value of 'search' is still there. Does this need to be removed with CSS / JavaScript or can it be done with Symfony?

Comment: I've updated the CSS, let me know if that removed the search value. If not, what browser are you using? You really don't want to set the value as empty in Symfony as screen readers will not be able to know what the button is for.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label in addition to pazulx's comment like so,

```
->add('search', 'submit', array(
    'label' => 'My label',
    'attr' => array('class' => 'my-custom-button-class'))
)
```